# Show that the fields are equal

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I have to show that $\mathbb{F}_{2^2}=\mathbb{Z}_2(a)$, where $a \in \mathbb{F}_{2^2}$ is of degree $2$ over $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

$$$$

To show this do I have to take first an element of $\mathbb{F}_{2^2}$ and show that it belongs also in $\mathbb{Z}_2(a)$??

Let $x\in \mathbb{F}_{2^2}$.

$x^{2^2}=x\Rightarrow x^{4}=x \Rightarrow x^{3}=1$

But how could I continue??

Comment: How many elements does each field have? Can you visualize how each field looks? Can you identify an isomorphism from one to the other?

Comment: @jef # $ \mathbb{F}_{2^2}=2^2=4$, # $ \mathbb{Z}_2(a)=3$ is it correct?? Do we maybe take $\phi : \mathbb{Z}_2(a) \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_{2^2} $ ??

Comment: This is important: http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @MaryStar First of all, in order for two fields to be isomorphic they must have the same size. Secondly, $\mathbb{Z}_2(a)$ contains 0, 1, and $a$ but it's also closed under sums and products.

Comment: @jef So, it contains also $a+1$. Therefore # $\mathbb{Z}_2(a)=4$, right??

Comment: @MaryStar Yes, it does contain $a-1$ which equals $a+1$ because $-1 = 1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2$. You can verify that these are the only elements by adding and multiplying these elements. Now you need an isomorphism. All isomorphisms map the zero element to the zero element and the one element to the one element. Now you only need worry about where the remaining two elements get mapped.

Comment: @jef I understand!!To find where the remaining two elements get mapped do we maybe use the identity of an element of $\mathbb{F}_{2^2}, a^{2^2}=a$??

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. It really helps if you visualize the two fields. For example, get a concrete idea of what $a$ is. Because $a$ is of degree 2, we know $a \in \mathbb{Z}_2$. Because $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is a field, $a$ is not a zero divisor. So now you know what $a^2$ is. Now you should understand what $\mathbb{Z}_2(a)$ is like and you can write tables for sums and products of its elements. Similarly, what is $\mathbb{F}_{2^2}$ like? It has size 4 and there are two possible additive groups of size 4, but only one has no zero divisors.

Comment: @jef I got stuck right now... I haven't understood why $a \in \mathbb{Z}_2$. If $a \in \mathbb{Z}_2$ why do we write $\mathbb{Z}_2(a)$ ??